# Misspellings in question titles

Tags: discussion, title

I've started to get annoyed about misspellings in question titles.

They're ugly, sloppy, and probably hurt searchability. Yes, I know there are lots of non-native speakers out there, and we can't expect perfect grammar and syntax, but misspellings seem pretty basic. Especially when the misspelling occurs in the name of a platform or technology or  tool.

I went through a couple of phases:

1. Fix the typo myself.
2. Leave a comment asking the OP to spell-check the title.
3. Downvote immediately, on the premise that misspellings in the title most likely indicate an overall level of sloppiness in thinking about the question or the programming issue behind it.
4. Ignore it--who cares?

Any suggestions about the best approach here?

Comment: Fix the typo for sure. Only DV based on the actual quality of the question, we all make misteaks 

Comment: You are making the assumption that people that google know how to spell correctly.  Wishful thinking, the more spelling corrections you make, the more crappy questions get added because a hapless programmer can't find anything :)

Comment: The title of this question needs to be changed to `Mispelings in question titles` pursuant to the Meta Punny Titles Act of 2011.

Comment: @HansPassant Google **IS** my spellchecker ;-)

Comment: @HansPassant, theoretically Search engines should handle the misspellings, since they suggest corrected spellings and other... nice algorithmic crap. "more crappy questions get added" - More crappy questions = more crappy duplicates = more `rel="canonical"` = better serach results. Either way, searching will regularly fail many people, regardless of spelling and every other attempt to improve SEO.

Comment: @Jakar serach results :P

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure I understand your comment. Do you mean that misspelled titles should be left alone so that other programmers who misspell the same words can find the question? Or did I fail to detect sarcasm (again).

Comment: @RobinHartland, yeah yeah lol. :P

Comment: This question is missing a mispelling in the title.

Comment: Your experience may differ from mine, but most programmers I know *are* born-native English speakers, and many of them are absolutely awful with spelling and grammar. I read work email routinely with spelling errors, no capital letters, missing punctuation, wrong its vs it's... it is not only people who speak English as a 2nd, 3rd language with this issue. It's not that they aren't smart people, they just aren't any good with English.

Comment: If you've got the energy, search for 'javscript' on SO.  This deviant variant of JavaScript turns up a lot, even in titles of questions (2,300 or so entries when I checked just now).  Oh, and in some of those questions, the misspelling is the crux of the problem and can't simply be fixed without rendering the question invalid.  Others — those in the title, for example — can be fixed without causing damage (indeed, it would benefit the site).  I doubt if that's the only such case.  And it's been a problem for years; I discussed it once before on MSO (before the MSO/MSE split).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't know whether to laugh or cry.

Comment: Sounds like what we really need is a new javascript UI framework called `javscript.js`!

Comment: @PeterTirrell I suggest `java.js` for maximum confusion and furiousness.

Comment: @Siguza yeah that pairs very nicely with the current trend to speak of "java scripts" :( Confusion at 105% and rising.

Comment: @Gimby And if you ask for clarification: "You know, the one that runs on any platform."

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Whenever you can edit and improve the post, do it and explain your changes in the "Edit Summary".

We're here to help each other in programming issues. I don't attempt to teach someone grammar or spelling, but whenever I feel I can improve, I do so.

Remember, we're programmers but not necessarily pro-grammars :)

Comment: `pro-grammars` Good point

Comment: I keep in mind that English may not be a first language, but when a poster has spelt a word three or four different ways in the same post I have to question whether they can get the syntax correct in a programming language.

Answer (score 26):

You're doing just about everything you could do in those scenarios, although I want to caution you on a bit of hubris here:

> ...but misspellings seem pretty basic. Especially when the misspelling occurs in the name of a platform or technology or tool.

Speaking chiefly from my own, personal interactions, a lot of non-native English speakers will spell words phonetically as opposed to structurally, which is why you may see unusual spellings or sentence structure in a sentence. For example, the article "an" in a place where it really shouldn't be.  You **can't** get *too* bent out of shape about that sort of thing since not everyone's raised speaking English.

It's far better to correct the spelling and sentence structure of a question than it is to merely downvote it, but don't feel obliged to.  I'd hate to see a question downvoted because it wasn't phrased correctly but was otherwise brilliant, and see another question *upvoted* but is completely and irredeemably off-topic.

Comment: I see this "not a native speaker" defence a lot. Not buying it. Spell checkers have existed for decades. They are integrated into all mainstream web browsers I've used in the last five years.

Comment: Spell checkers do not defend against all cases, e.g. homophones are very difficult for non-native speakers (and for many native speakers as well).

Comment: To add on @DanLowe's point:  "your" and "you're" are two different words that should be used in two different contexts, but modern browser's spell check isn't able to tell which one your supposed to use and when.

Comment: @DanLowe I think you're wrong about that. http://i.imgur.com/r1HaIHV.png

Comment: @Ajedi32 Test it in every OS / browser combo in common use and we'll see.. :) Also note, someone who normally speaks/writes in a different language may not have an English spell checker active in their OS/browser.

Comment: @Ajedi32:  You must be using Windows.  I'm not.  Where would I get that kind of grammar-checking feature? ;)

Comment: @Makoto I am using Windows currently, but I'm pretty sure it works on any OS, as it's a feature of Chrome. You do have to turn on network-assisted spell checking though: chrome://settings/search#resolve%20spelling%20errors

Comment: That's a solution, but not everyone has it turned on. @Ajedi32

Comment: @Makoto Yep, I'm aware of that. Just wanted to point out that it does in fact exist and is built-in to at least one modern browser.

Answer (score 5):

There's a case where instead of correcting the misspelling, it is better to rewrite the whole title. Like [problemo](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aproblemo), [erro](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aerro) and many others. If you find a title with a misspelling, chances are that there is more stuff to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Often enough I come across spelling and/or letter casing errors in the browsers themselves ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272619/javascript-readasdataurl-is-not-a-function/30272620)) and it's important to take notice if the one error you spotted is the *only* error sometimes as it may be indicative of intentionally referencing something of error intentionally.

In general, back to the original context of the question: I agree that this is a platform  for programming, not grammar and spelling, though it is not inappropriate to comment (*politely*) with a link to [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/) and even a specific topic especially if you have a high level of certainty that a pronounced inadequate level of grammar may be leading someone to misinterpret something somewhere.

Comment: "intentionally referencing something of error intentionally": sorry, but what does that mean?

Comment: @NickCox I think he means that the error in the misspelling could be the reason for the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me there is a BIG difference between incorrect English, and misspelling of names of technology and tools.

Incorrect English doesn't seem like such a big problem to me. I'm a non-native English speaker and although I realise my English is quite good, it's sometimes so disheartening to get negative reactions just because your grammar and spelling are not perfect. This seems to me a place to answer questions relating to programming, not a 'perfect English safe place' for people who can't handle typos.

Misspelling of names of technology and tools is a problem though. It hurts searchability. Who cares if that person is 'sloppy'- if the question is otherwise good, I'd just edit.

Comment: I don't think anyone claims that the major issue is small typos. There are more important issues. 1. Sometimes the standard of English is so poor that the question is more, even too, difficult to understand: that's a problem for everyone, including the OP. 2. Searchability is compromised by misspelling of technical terms, as you mention. 3. It may seem that the OP just isn't trying to write clearly or to check their post. Lack of attention to detail is especially worrying in a programming forum.  All of these can and do also arise with people whose first language is English.